# Non-perturbative approach to QFT in Hamiltonian formalism?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, non-perturbative

A simple conceptual question today: is it true that QFT can only be approached in a non-perturbative way only through the functional methods (like 1/N), while in the Hamiltonian formalism we can only do the perturbation theory?

In QM, the functional methods are, of course, widely-known for finding the non-perturbative corrections [1](http://www.tpi.umn.edu/shifman/lectures4students/ABC_of_Instantons.pdf). However, there also exist certain methods based on the Hamiltonian formalism. For example, studying the resolvent operator of the Schrodinger equation [2](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0501136). Alternatively, one can employ the Uniform WKB quantisation condition [3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.5202).

I know that in QFT people also construct the trans-series expansions. But what methods do they use?..

Comment: My attitude is that in the Hamiltonian formulation the space of states is *much* too gigantic to make tractable calculations.  I have seen people in the mid-80's trying to apply variational methods to get at the ground state wave function of the fields.  Anyway, I do find that it is certainly useful to think about it for conceptual reasons.

Comment: This [review paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3991) might be relevant, in particular section 2 which discusses full, rigorous constructions of (low-dimensional) interacting QFTs in the Hamiltonian formalism.